# Why is nested CSS selector applied from bottom-up?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I understand that in nested CSS rules, the selector is applied from the most nested one, going bottom-up. For example in the following:

```
.foo > .bar .baz{
  ...
}
```

`.baz` elements are selected from the page, then it is restricted to those that are descendants of `.bar`, then it is restricted to those that are childs of `.foo`. Why does it work this way? I read that this is causing inefficiency in nested CSS rules. In most cases, I believe top-down restriction would be more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient selector would require no traversal - it would simply apply to the element in question.

Whether you traverse from the top down or the bottom up it would be less efficient than no traversal.

Bottom-up is more efficient than top down because you only traverse where the selector matches - so if the current element is not `.baz` nothing more needs to be done. If it is a `.baz` you check ancestry for a `.bar` and repeat until you either fail a condition or match all the selectors.

Also, you are trying to work out whether to apply a style to the element, so you have one element and you determine matching styles. If you worked top-down you would be working on divergent matching, rather than convergent matching i.e. if you start at `.foo` you'll potentially find many matches for selectors to the right of the style rule - so you end up with trees of matching elements to check.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, I have been wondering about this for quite a while now.